# Can website detect if a specific app in iOS/Android scraping its web site?

Tags: javascript, ios, dom, web-scraping

Is real to detect if one app running on iOS/Android is scraping my site?
I mean some app loading my webpage then puts a script into contentController(iOS) and runs it when page loaded , then script analyzing my page gets some information from my webpage? Is it somehow possible to detect that this app was doing it in my website?

literally i have an app that parses google.translate results. Changes it(info from google) and puts it in. Can really google detect and prove that exactly my app got results from its site? Can google really detect that it was scraping? (Again my app changes results of google.translate output so it not similar to google.translate output) I know this is illegal and violating terms of use but google itself provokes doing so

Comment: No it is not possible through normal means to determine what sort of client is issuing HTTP requests to your server. Clients can actively impersonate whatever they want.

Comment: Can you please provide the code how you achieve that ?

Answer (score -1):

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```

To check if user is from Specific device

```
if( isMobile.iOS() ) alert('iOS');
```